# Recording at 60 FPS

Tags: performance, recording

I use Bandicam to record.
My game runs at 80+ FPS and I want to record 60 FPS videos. When I start recording, my in-game FPS drops to about 40+ but the recorded file shows 60 FPS.

Does my recorded gameplay really 60 or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 60 fps recording of a 40 fps game is still a recording of a 40 fps game. At best, it will essentially be the same as a 40 fps recording (with a larger file size). At worst, it will actually reduce the quality.